# efficient way to union non-set iterables within groups

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have this `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        A=['b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a'],
        B=[[0, 2, 3, 1],
           [9, 6, 7, 2],
           [6, 0, 1, 4],
           [9, 2, 5, 1],
           [5, 1, 4, 8],
           [8, 5, 6, 6],
           [0, 9, 0, 0],
           [2, 6, 1, 8],
           [7, 3, 2, 6],
           [8, 7, 1, 9]]
        ))
```

I want to group by `'A'` and union all the lists in `'B'`

Neither `df.groupby('A').B.union()` nor `df.groupby('A').B.apply(set.union)` work.

I want the result to be

```
A
a    {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
b                {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6}
c                {1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9}
Name: B, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you need to cast them as sets first before applying the union. One solution would be to use `sum` to concatenate the groups, then cast to set using `map`

```
In [28]: df.groupby('A').B.sum().map(set)
Out[28]:
A
a    {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
b                {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6}
c                {1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9}
dtype: object
```

Comment: Is the second `map` necessary?  Works fine for me without it.

Comment: Yeah, the set construction should be enough, you're just taking the union of a single set at the end.

Comment: Very elegant solution!

Comment: @root of course you're right, not sure what i was thinking

Answer (score 2):

maxymoo's answer is nice, but since it first adds all the lists together it might unnecessarily take a lot of memory (especially so if there are lots of duplicates).

Instead, you should first convert column `B` to sets, after which you can reduce to a single set much more efficiently. Like this:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].map(set)

   A             B
0  b  {0, 1, 2, 3}
1  a  {9, 2, 6, 7}
2  b  {0, 1, 4, 6}
3  c  {9, 2, 5, 1}
4  a  {8, 1, 4, 5}
5  c     {8, 5, 6}
6  a        {0, 9}
7  c  {8, 1, 2, 6}
8  a  {2, 3, 6, 7}
9  a  {8, 1, 9, 7}

df.groupby('A').B.apply(lambda x: reduce(set.union, x))

A
a    {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
b                {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6}
c                {1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9}
Name: B, dtype: object
```

Or, as a one-liner, as maxymoo points out:

```
df.groupby('A').B.apply(lambda x : reduce(set.union, x.map(set)))
```

Comment: yeh this is better than my answer

Comment: actually if you want a one-liner, you could use `df.groupby('A').B.apply(lambda x : reduce(set.union, x.map(set)))` and include the datatype conversion in the lambda

Comment: actually this is even better `df.groupby('A').B.apply(lambda x : reduce(set.union, x, set(x.iloc[0])))`, using Harry's answer's observation that only the first argument in `union` needs to be a set

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a function to apply with

```
def f(x):
    # grabbing first one so I can
    # make a set out of it
    first, *rest = x.values.tolist()
    # union won't work unless it's on
    # a set, it doesn't care about the rest
    return set(first).union(*rest)

df.groupby('A').B.apply(f)

A
a    {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
b                {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6}
c                {1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9}
Name: B, dtype: object
```